# Why is the Pinel SCPI expected yield twice lower than a normal SCPI?

Tags: taxes, france, reit

I read on https://www.capital.fr/immobilier/les-scpi-fiscales-une-solution-pour-baisser-ses-impots-et-bloquer-son-epargne-1114747  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022203923/https://www.capital.fr/immobilier/les-scpi-fiscales-une-solution-pour-baisser-ses-impots-et-bloquer-son-epargne-1114747)):

> Entre temps, le rendement espéré sera, comme pour les SCPI Pinel, de l’ordre de 2% à 2,5% par an, soit deux fois moins que pour des SCPI classiques.

Which Google [translates](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Entre%20temps%2C%20le%20rendement%20esp%C3%A9r%C3%A9%20sera%2C%20comme%20pour%20les%20SCPI%20Pinel%2C%20de%20l%E2%80%99ordre%20de%202%25%20%C3%A0%202%2C5%25%20par%20an%2C%20soit%20deux%20fois%20moins%20que%20pour%20des%20SCPI%20classiques) as:

> Meanwhile, the expected yield will, as for Pinel SCPI, be in the range of 2% to 2.5% per year, which is two times less than for conventional SCPIs

Why is the Pinel SCPI expected yield twice lower than a normal SCPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two factors (there could be more):

- The SCPI takes around 12% fees on everything (initial investment + rent), according to https://www.la-loipinel.fr/scpi-pinel/scpi-urban-vitalim-2/  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171024232757/https://www.la-loipinel.fr/scpi-pinel/scpi-urban-vitalim-2/)) ("Frais de gestion annuelle    12% TTC basés sur les produits locatifs HT encaissés et sur les produits financiers nets")
- SCPI Pinel is a special SCPI with rents below market prices (hence the tax incentive), only in dedicated areas (where maybe prices don't raise as fast as elsewhere?), and to low income tenants. From http://www.cabinet-roche.com/en/all-you-need-to-know-on-the-pinel-device/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171024233246/http://www.cabinet-roche.com/en/all-you-need-to-know-on-the-pinel-device/)):

[image]

[image]